# How do I create a subdirectory in html?

Tags: html, subdirectory

For example, my website is mywebsite.com. On that site I have a page called "countries.html" with a list of countries on it. When a user clicks on the country (say Japan) it brings them to a page, "Japan.html".

I want that Japan page to be under the countries page: mywebsite.com/countries/Japan.html. How do I create that subdirectory in HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

Assuming you are using static files, you create the directory on the file system of your webserver.

Then you use it in the path for the `href` attribute of the link.

```
<a href="countries/Japan.html">
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question and already answered, I know, but I think there is a better way to do this (if going by the asker's current setup and intended result).

Create a folder named `countries` in your root directory and put all the country files there. You then move your `countries.html` file to the `countries` folder and change the name from `countries.html` to `index.html`.

So the new structure would look like this:

```
├── index.html
└── countries
    ├── index.html
    └── Japan.html
```

And you would link to the countries list page (your (formerly) `countries.html` file):

```
<a href="/countries/">Link to the countries folder index file</a>
```

<sup>No need to include the `index.html` in the href URL. When you link to a directory like this, it (by default) automatically looks for an index file and, if it exists, serves it.</sup>

And then in the countries directory, your links to specific countries would look like this:

```
<a href="Japan.html">Link to Japan relative to current folder (NOT RECOMMENDED)</a>

<a href="/countries/Japan.html>Link to Japan relative to the document root (RECOMMENDED)</a>
```

Don't have any sources, but it just feels cleaner and makes more sense to have the countries list page appear as a directory rather than a file.

Which site structure looks better?

1. **Countries list `countries.html` as a separate file**

   - Page with the countries list - `http://mywebsite.com/countries.html`
   - Page about Japan - `http://mywebsite.com/countries/Japan.html`
2. **Countries list as `index.html` file in the countries directory**

   - Page with the countries list - `http://mywebsite.com/countries/`
   - Page about Japan - `http://mywebsite.com/countries/Japan.html`

Answer (score 0):

The software you use to create your website should show you a list of files, and in that area there's usually the option to create a subdirectory.  Do that, put your country files in the subdirectory, create the links as suggested by others, and you're done.

The file structure is separate from HTML and creating pages.

Comment: this is not a answer, use comments area to ask more details to user.

Comment: Rewrote the answer to be an answer instead of a question.  I had enough rep to answer, but not to comment.  Seems odd...

Answer (score 0):

For a basic website, with static HTML, your pages follow the file structure of your website.

Take the following file structure for example:

```
index.html
about.html
countries/
    Japan.html
    Norway.html
```

If you want to create a link to `Japan.html` from `index.html`, the link would have to be to `mywebsite.com/countries/Japan.html`.